# How to find a specific key in a PHP array

Tags: php

Please find below my array

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 0 
    [country] => GB 
    [note] => coda@knoppys.co.uk 
    [cost] => 
    [company] => Aberdeen Debenhams 
    [address_1] => 
    [address_2] => Trinity Centre 
    [city] => 
    [state] => 
    [postcode] => AB11 6BD 
    [phone] => 01224 578553 
) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [country] => GB 
    [note] => 
    [cost] => 
    [company] => Basildon Debenhams 
    [address_1] => 
    [address_2] => The Eastgate Centre 
    [city] => 
    [state] => 
    [postcode] => SS14 1HR 
    [phone] => 01268 244456 
)
)
```

The array is stored in the DB as a serialized array as a single WordPress Option.

I have a string:

```
$storename = 'Aberdeen Debenhams';
```

I have a function I use to search multidimensional arrays for a string.

```
if(search_array($storename, $option)) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Now this rings true which is fine. The `$storename` is dynamic and comes from a previous function. What I need to do is be able to get the value of the `[note]` key within the same array so I can take that onto my next function.

UPDATE: In order for my next function to work I am using the following code to get the email address (key->note) from the same array as the `$storename`

```
//Get the email address of the storename                    
$key = array_search($storename, array_column($option,'company'));
echo $option[$key]['note'];
```

However, I am now getting the following.

Storename: Aberdeen Debenhams
Email: coda@knoppys.co.uk

Storename: Basildon Debenhams
Email: coda@knoppys.co.uk

It seems to be echoing the email address from the first array only.

Comment: echo $key = array_search($storename, $option);

Comment: Thanks @Amit but that didnt give me the note key, nor any other key. I need to get the value of the note key inside the same array as the $storename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aray_search()` along with `array_column()`:-

```
echo $key = array_search($storename, array_column($option,'company'));

echo PHP_EOL;

echo $option[$key]['note'];
```

*Output:-https://eval.in/737875   OR  https://eval.in/737876  Or https://eval.in/737899*

Note:-

this solution will work in the case of numeric-indexed array, not associative array.

***Use `if ($key !== false) { echo ... }` suggested by @Kodos Johnson***

Comment: sorry I got your name wrong. I have made an update, your code is working but its only getting the first [note] from the arrays.

Comment: @AlexKnopp  it's working for your update question too,check here:- https://eval.in/737899   ($storename  need to be changed otherwise always get same value)

Comment: @AlexKnopp You should make sure that `$key` is not `false` before you use it. So do `if ($key !== false) { echo ... } `. This is because `array_search` returns `false` if the value was not found, and when you use `false` as the key for an array, it will assume 0 which is the first element of the array.

Comment: @Anant, thanks for the help. Adding the if statement fixed hte issues with returning the same email address.

Comment: @AlexKnopp  glad to help you . :):)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with an iteration, as below, also If you have an array of companies you can set `foreach()` that iterates companies in the big `foreach()`.

```
foreach(array as arr){

   $aberdeen=new array();
   $basildon= new array();

   if(arr['company']=="Aberdeen Debenhams")
      $aberdeen = $arr;


    if(arr['company']=="Basildon Debenhams")
      $basildon = $arr;
 }

$basildon['note']; //(empty)
$aberden['note'];  //coda@knoppys.co.uk
```